# Disabling Touch Simulation in Firefox Renders HTML/CSS Differently

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I’m new to web-dev and don’t know if this is working as intended, but it seems odd to me. Briefly, disabling touch even simulation causes my webpage to be rendered differently (see attached photos). Is this due to my code, Firefox dev tools, or something else?

Thanks.

`Code Here:` [Codepen](https://codepen.io/stephenwist/pen/KKMRPaR)
[image: Touch Simulation ON]
[image: Touch Simulation OFF]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543021/responsive-view-on-firefox-developer-tools-show-wrong-width This might be the answer

Comment: maybe https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1521159

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the following code to the `head` section (before `title` tag):

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

From [HEAD](https://github.com/joshbuchea/HEAD)

> - `meta name="viewport"` - viewport settings related to mobile responsiveness
> - `width=device-width` means that it will use the physical width of the device (instead of zooming out) which is good with mobile-friendly pages
> - `initial-scale=1` is the initial zoom, 1 means no zoom

For more info about `viewport` meta tag see: [Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: I still want to know why this different width happens. Without the viewport meta tag some pages have smaller width, some don't.